# New sheet created reference within same code

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a new sheet with a specific name with the following formula:

```
    With ThisWorkbook
        .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = Range("B2") & "_MCT"
    End With
```

so the new sheet will be named "X_MCT", X being the value in cell B2.

In this same code I'm adding a code that wants to fill this new sheet with values from the original sheet. Is there a way to do this? Below is an example equation I have that's going into the newly created sheet:

```
Sheets("MCT").Cells(i + 6, 2 * j + j - 2 + 1) = "*FORCES-DEFORMATION FUNCTION    ; Forces-Deformation Function"'''
```

I've defined the i's and j's but is there a way to change that "MCT" to the new "X_MCT" that the code creates? Or should I replace it with the "Active sheet function" since when I create the new sheet, it becomes the active sheet. My first idea is preferred since it's cleaner.

Below is an example I'd like to make work:

```
Sub newsheet()

With ThisWorkbook
        Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = Range("B2") & "_MCT"
        
       
    End With
    
 Sheets(Range("B2") & "_MCT").Cells(1, 1) = "*FORCES-DEFORMATION FUNCTION    ; Forces-Deformation Function"

End Sub
```

But I get an "Out of Range error" the text doesn't get written into this new sheet. Only by running the macro again does a new sheet get created with that text, but why doesn't it work on the original sheet?

Comment: You could reference it either as `.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)` since it will be the last one, or as `.Sheets(Range("B2") & "_MCT")` (but I'm surprised that `Range("B2")` isn't qualified with any worksheet reference)

Comment: @SpectralInstance thank you, I've tried this but it partially works, please see the code I've edited in my main question.

Comment: I had intended for you to include either line _within_ the `With...End With` construct (i.e. I preceded both with `.`) - your code makes it look like you have multiple workbooks open, so `Sheets(Range("B2") & "_MCT").Cells(1, 1)` is implicitly referencing `ActiveWorkbook`, which isn't necessarily the same as `ThisWorkbook` (and it would also help if you qualified `Range("B2")` with the parent worksheet reference, which should be in the appropriate workbook)

Comment: @SpectralInstance I see, thank you for clarifying, I'm very new to VBA and learning the syntax so I appreciate you bearing with me while I learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub NewSheet()
  With ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    Dim Reference as Worksheet
    Set Reference = .Item("A worksheet with B2")
    With .Add(After:=.Item(.Count))
      .Name = Reference.Range("B2") & "_MCT"
      .Cells(1, 1) = "*FORCES-DEFORMATION FUNCTION    ; Forces-Deformation Function"       
    End with
  End With
End Sub
```

You got an *Out of range* error because of `Sheets(Range("B2") & "_MCT")` on the last line of your code. `Range("B2")` in this case refers to the newly created sheet and is empty. Therefore, this code is trying to access the "_MCT" sheet, which, I guess, doesn't exist. That's where *Subscript out of range* happens.

Comment: This worked perfectly, similar to what @SpectralInstance suggested, do I need to put all the code that I have which references the newly created sheet within the second `With` and the first `End with` ?

Comment: @D89  It's up to you. You can do this, but you're not obliged. As @SpectralInstance have mentioned, what really helps is to prepend `Range(...)` with an appropriate worksheet reference to be sure  that you address the right range. In the _object module_ of a worksheet you know exactly that `Range` refers to the cells of that sheet. While in a _standard module_ when used without an object qualifier , `Range(...)` is a shortcut for `ActiveSheet.Range(...)`, which can lead to unpredictable behavior and result.

Comment: Is it possible to set the `.item("worksheet with B2")` as the current active worksheet? For example, if I wanted to set this macro to run on Sheet A (where B2 is located) and the created sheet Sheet B/MCT will be populated from items in Sheet A, is there a way to set the formulas I create within the `With` `End With` to pick off of values from Sheet A?

Comment: To your last comment, eventually I'd like to copy Sheet A to a Sheet A1 and run the macro to create a new Sheet B1, so I'm trying to figure out the best way to do that. So I'd like the macro to be able to know where I'm referencing things from Sheet A originally, to automatically know it's Sheet A1 now that the new data is going to come from. I hope I'm clear with what I'd like to accomplish, I'm new to VBA so thinking in these logical terms is a new process for me.

Comment: @D89 You call it directly like `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("name of the A").Range(...)`.  I prefer to avoid ActiveSheet, ActiveCell, ect. But yes, you can activate an arbitrary sheet like `Sheets("whatever the name").Activate` Some links on the topic: [Using With statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-with-statements) and [Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)) and [What is a VBA Module](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/what-is-a-vba-module/)

Comment: Thanks so much, I'll explore those topics and become more acquainted with these functions.

Comment: The "whatever the name", can that be a variable that refers to the active sheet name that the macro is placed on? Without having to specify the name of that sheet within the macro code.

Comment: @D89 Yes, it can. But to be honest, I'm not sure I understand the question. It can be interpreted in two ways. So I better leave a [link that I think might be helpful](https://www.wallstreetmojo.com/vba-worksheets/)